# Software for offline collaborative writing

Tags: open-source, offline, collaboration

I am the secretary of a students' organisation. In our assemblies, me and 2-3 assistants have to take minutes. Until now, we have used Google Docs to edit the file at the same time. However, since it's roughly 250 people present and logged in the wifi, and the wifi in most hotels or universities isn't that capable, we have serious problems when the connection drops.

I am searching for some way that allows collaborative writing, **off the internet**, between a team of 3-4 people. Something involving setting up a local network can also work. Would love if it works with both Windows and Mac. Open source is also greatly appreciated.

Edit: Our terms in office are annual, so I'm also interested in a solution rather easy to use with people not *that* profficient in computers. Not mandatory though :)

Comment: Generally spoken, if you use something based on Markdown, HTML or the likes (i.e. "plain ASCII" formats), you could combine that with a VCS like Git. Each of you have their own copy of the repository (here: document tree), and as soon as you have network stuff can be pushed and merged. A different approach would be using your own hotspot (e.g. provided by some Android device) and be able to work online again. In both cases, cross-platform is no issue. Just my 2 cents; there might be something better out there which you hopefully see in answers soon :)

Comment: I like the first idea, although it might be difficult to use after I am out of office, since I have moderate computing knowledge but someone else might not. If no other solution is proposed, I could do that and write a guide :) Mobile hotspot just doesn't work in some places :P Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Be welcome to ask then for suitable Markdown clients for the different platforms if you need :)

Answer (score 3):

[Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/) meets your requirements, as far as I understand:

- Collaborative text editor with a web interface.
- Supports Windows/Unix/Mac.
- Fully open source.
- Installation is straightforward.

[image: Etherpad screenshot]

You didn't mention which type of documents are you planning to work with. If you only need basic text editing, Etherpad should do the job.